# Will Fledge ever show me some gratitude?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

When I woke up at night in my room at the Knight Academy, I heard a *very unexpected* sound coming from the room next door. Investigating, I found Fledge doing push-ups, trying to get stronger. I've helped him *twice* now, and he's still not satisfied. **Will he ever succeed and show some gratitude for my help?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fledge's sidequest is a multistage one. Every stage is unlocked by your advancement in the main quest.

There are 3 stages:

1. Unlocking the sidequest. Fledge will be painfully doing push-ups. When you speak to him, his push-ups count will be around 5. Give him a stamina potion.
2. Another boost. Fledge's push-up count will be up to 50ish. Give him another stamina potion.
3. Reaping the reward. Fledge's push-up count will be up in the 3000's. He will give you 5 gratitude crystals.

You have to wait a while (read at least one step forward in the main quest) before seeing the results of giving Fledge a stamina potion.

Comment: It's possible that the advancement is triggered by specific main quest progress, in which case you might not have to wait as long between steps if you're already far along - otherwise if you started the side quest when near the end of the game, it wouldn't be finishable! (But I'm not sure.)

Comment: @Jefromi: In those circumstances, you just need to be at a certain point in the game. On my first playthrough of the game, I didn't realize he had multiple phases in his quest. I only gave him the first potion and always saw him in the day with the little quest icon over him in the day. Every time I spoke to him (when I first noticed it), he always said "thanks" but never seemed to say anything else so I ignored it until much much later. It was only when I reached the end of the game that I realized that I needed to give him another potion. After visiting the next night, I got the crystals.

Answer (score 2):

You need to help him by giving him a stamina potion one more time (for a total of three times) in order for him to show gratitude.

He will show his gratitude by:

> Giving you 5 gratitude crystals.

Comment: This also unlocks a minigame which I really need to ask about.